# How to make a MLModel updatable in Swift CoreML?

Tags: python, swift, keras, coreml, mlmodel

I'm trying to implement the new CoreML 3 feature of updatable Models into my App, but I can't figure it out.

Im creating a Neural Network with 2 layers in Keras and convert it to a core ML Model. Then I include the model into my iOS Project. 
However `self.testmodel.model.modelDescription.isUpdatable` is always false, and I can't make sense of the apple docs.

```py
model = Sequential([
    Dense(10, activation="sigmoid", input_shape=(2,)),
    Dense(2, activation="relu"),
])
core_mlmodel = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)
core_mlmodel.save("FirstNN.mlmodel")
```

Integrated in Swift I can now use the Model, but can't update it

```swift
let testmodel = FirstNN()
try testmodel.prediction(input: input) // works
testmodel.model.modelDescription.isUpdatable  // is false
```

Why isn't my model updatable and how can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `respect_trainable=True` argument to `coremltools.converters.keras.convert()`.

Alternatively, you can change the mlmodel file after the conversion to make the model updatable. Official documentation in the form of examples is here: https://github.com/apple/coremltools/tree/master/examples/updatable_models

Comment: Ahh, I see, you also need to use the beta version `3.0b5` of coremltools. That makes sense. Thank you very much

Comment: However trying to update the model throws the error: [espresso] Training kernels not enabled for engine: 100 And doesn’t update

Comment: @SebastianJ.Vogt I keep receiving the same message, however the model updating is working in my case. Are you using [modelName]TrainingInput class for providing training inputs?

Comment: I just haven't saved the model in the completion handler